# Why does this window subclassing code crash?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, dll

I am trying to subclass the window that currently has focus. I do this by monitoring for `HCBT_ACTIVATE` events using a CBT hook, and set and unset the `WndProc` of the focused and previously focused windows.

**The problem is that it only works whenever I have a breakpoint set somewhere in the code**.

If there is no breakpoint, once my application exits, all the windows that I have subclassed  crashes in order, even though I have removed the subclassing and restored the original WndProc.

I have verified that `Unsubclass()` is called whenever my application shuts down.

```
// code extracts
HINSTANCE hInst;
HHOOK hHook;

#pragma data_seg(".shared")
HWND hWndSubclass = 0;
FARPROC lpfnOldWndProc = NULL;
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:.shared,rws")

void Unsubclass()
{
    // if the window still exists
    if (hWndSubclass != 0 && IsWindow(hWndSubclass))
    {
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWndSubclass, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LPARAM)lpfnOldWndProc);
        hWndSubclass = 0;
    }
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK SubClassFunc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (message == WM_MOVING)
    {
        // this is just test code so I can see it works (it does)
        RECT* r = (RECT*)lParam;
        r->right = r->left + 500;
        r->bottom = r->top + 500;
        return TRUE;
    }
    else if (message == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        Unsubclass();
    }
    return CallWindowProc((WNDPROC)lpfnOldWndProc, hWndSubclass, message, wParam, lParam);
}

void SubclassWindow(HWND hWnd)
{
    // remove the subclassing for the old window
    Unsubclass();
    // subclass the new window
    lpfnOldWndProc = (FARPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LPARAM)SubClassFunc);
    hWndSubclass = hWnd;
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE)
    {
        SubclassWindow((HWND)wParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// ... code that initializes the CBT proc
__declspec(dllexport) BOOL Setup()
{
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, hInst, 0);
}

__declspec(dllexport) BOOL Teardown()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    Unsubclass();
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, 
                       DWORD  Reason, 
                       LPVOID Reserved
                     )
{
    switch(Reason)
    { 
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            hInst = hInstance;
            return TRUE;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            Unsubclass();
            return TRUE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: hWndServer is irrelevant (it is the process that sets up the CBT hook). I've removed the reference to it.

Comment: Is it possible that after the final Unsubclass the hook is still active and still subclasses windows during the shutdown?

Comment: @DR: that is my fear too. But as far as I can tell, it should be immediate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997565.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems hinge on several fronts:

- UnHookWindowsHook does not unload injected dlls, all it does is remove the hook proc. If the dlls need to be unloaded its up to them to invent some kind of unloading mechanism.
- SetWindowLongPtr typically fails when called from a process other than the process that owns the window.

The nett result of this is, its very difficult to safely remove windows hooks. First thing, your OldWindowProc pointer should not be stored in the shared data area. Next, in order to remove the subclass, you need to be able to co-erce the (currently) subclassed process to perform the un-subclassing.

What you could do is, first, register a new unique message id and place it in your shared area using RegisterWindowMessage. `WM_REMOVE_HOOK`.

```
UINT idWM_REMOVE_HOOK = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_REMOVE_HOOK");
```

Now, whenever you need to remove a hook,

```
SendMessage(hWndSubClass,idWM_REMOVE_HOOK,0,0);
```

In your subclass proc:

```
if(uMsg == WM_DESTROY || uMsg == idWM_REMOVE_HOOK)
{
  Unsubclass(hwnd);
}
```

Remove the call to UnSubClass in DLL_PROCESS_DETATCH. Its a dangerous race condition thats going to cause your dll being unloaded in some random process to trash the hook data of a potentially valid hook in another process.

Answer (score 0):

lpfnOldWndProc and hWndSubclass are global pointers. Seems like you've got only one per process. What if a process creates more than one window?

Then you will unsubclass only the last one.

EDIT: Also, why do you tear down in Process DETACH?

Comment: That doesn't matter, if I understand you correctly. Only one window can have focus at a time. I only need to have access to the focused window. Whenever the focus changes to a new window, the old subclassing is removed, and the now focused window receives the focus.

Comment: @EFraim: Does it matter that you have more than one UI thread? I am only subclassing a single window *instance* at a time.

Comment: @Vegard: Of course it can. What if you have a race condition between threads? (i.e. if doing something on a window belonging to a different thread) That's unlikely but still possible.

Comment: @EFraim: It might just be me, but I can't see the possibility of a race condition here (but my Win32-experience is limited). Could you outline one scenario in which that could happen?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a global system-wide hook in a DLL.  You need to store the HHOOK handle and your subclassing information in a block of shared memory so all instances of your DLL in all running processes can have access to them.  Your variables are declared global in code, but each individual instance of the DLL will have its own local copy of them, and thus they will not be not initialized in all but 1 of your DLL instances (the one that calls Setup()).  They need to be shared globally within the entire system instead.

You also should not be calling TearDown() in DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, either.  Every instance of the DLL is going to call TearDown() when their respective processes terminate, but only the single instance that actually called Setup() should be the one to call Teardown().

Comment: +1: This sounds like the money.  I've been bitten by the "globals not in shared memory" issue before when setting a systemwide hook.

Comment: 1. The HHOOK handle does not need to be in shared memory. The handle is only necessary in the process that calls Setup() and Teardown(). 2. You are right, Teardown() should not be called on process detach. However, it should Unsubclass(). I will fix this now. 3. Putting the subclassing information in shared memory changes nothing; the process of every window I touch when this is running still crashes when I shut down my app (I had already tried this to no avail, but forgot to include it in the question).

Comment: @Vegard: the HHOOK has to be shared, because every instance of the DLL must pass the same HHOOK to CallNextHookEx() whenever the hook function is called within their local application processes.  Only certain hook types are called in the same DLL instance that calls SetWindowsHookEx().  Other hook types are not, thus the HHOOK has to be shared.

Comment: @Vegard: also, keep in mind that releasing a global hook DOES NOT unload the active DLL instances!  SetWindowsHookEx() for a global hook causes implicit calls to LoadLibrary() in each running process, however UnhookWindowsHookEx() does not have access to other processes, and thus cannot force them to call FreeLibrary(). Microsoft's documentation even says as much.  So the subclassing info should be shared, because the DLL instance that calls UnhookWindowsHookEx() needs to know if there is an active subclass so it can tell that owning DLL to unsubclass before the hook is finall released.

Comment: @Remy : hhook seems to be a legacy of windows. It's safe to use 0 as a hHook to call the next hook on NT platforms according to the MSDN CallNextHookEx documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If the debugger will cause the process to succeed by adding a breakpoint then most likely, this is a timing issue.
What possibly happens is that your main application is closing itself and freeing resources just before the subclassed windows get the messages they need to remove the subclass again. You might want to give them a few processing cycles to handle their own messages between the unhooking and the unsubclassing. (In Delphi you could do this by calling Application.ProcessMessages but in your C++ version? Don't know the answer to that.