# Prevent listview from resizing column not work in winapi

Tags: windows, listview, winapi, mfc

I am using vc 6.0. I am trying to prevent user from resize a column in a listview using winapi. I want to prevent the first column(width: 0) from resizing.

I am following codes (1)[winapi-listview-cant-prevent-columns-from-resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325887/winapi-listview-cant-prevent-columns-from-resizing) (2)[Prevent-column-resizing](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/columns/article.php/c1065/Prevent-column-resizing.htm) . But It not work.

My function which to handle message is follow:

```
#define HANDLE_WM_NOTIFY(hwnd, wParam, lParam, fn) \
    (fn)((hwnd), (int)(wParam), (NMHDR FAR*)(lParam))
```

What did I try:

**1**

```
BOOL Present_OnNotify(HWND hwnd, int id, LPNMHDR lParam)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        case IDC_LIST_PRESLIST: 
        {
            HD_NOTIFY *pHDN = (HD_NOTIFY*)lParam;
            if(lParam->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKW || lParam->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKA || lParam->code == HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKA || lParam->code == HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKW ) 
            {
                if(0==ListView_GetColumnWidth(hwnd,pHDN->iItem))
                { 
                    DWORD dwMaskedItem = 0L;
                    DWORD m_dwNoSizeCols = 1L;

                    if (pHDN->iItem < 32)
                    {
                        dwMaskedItem = (0x01 << pHDN->iItem);
                    }
                    dwMaskedItem &= m_dwNoSizeCols; 
                    if (dwMaskedItem != 0L)
                    {
                        return TRUE; 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**2**

```
BOOL Present_OnNotify(HWND hwnd, int id, LPNMHDR lParam)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        case IDC_LIST_PRESLIST: 
        {
            HD_NOTIFY *pHDN = (HD_NOTIFY*)lParam;
            if(lParam->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKW || lParam->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKA || lParam->code == HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKA || lParam->code == HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKW ) 
            {
                if(0==ListView_GetColumnWidth(hwnd,pHDN->iItem))
                { 
                    SetWindowLong(hwnd, DWL_MSGRESULT, TRUE);
                    return TRUE; 
                }
```

Acturally, I am not understand too much about the first code which follow (2)[Prevent-column-resizing](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/columns/article.php/c1065/Prevent-column-resizing.htm). But the second should be work. What should I do? Did I miss something? Thanks.

**EDIT**

My current Code:

I have tried to subclassing the listview control as follow. There is no compile errors. But when the dialog(maybe the listview) is being created, it is crashed. I have no clue about this. I created listview from resource.

***Head file***

```
BOOL WINAPI Present_Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
BOOL Present_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam);
void Present_OnCommand(HWND hwnd, int id, HWND hwndCtl, UINT codeNotify);
void Present_OnClose(HWND hwnd);

void InitPresLVColumn(HWND hwnd);
BOOL Present_OnNotify(HWND hWnd, int id, LPNMHDR lParam); //to handle WM_NOTIFY message
LRESULT CALLBACK PresListView_OnNotify(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); // function to handle message override from parent
```

***Source file***

*Message crackers of the dialog*

```
BOOL WINAPI Present_Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_INITDIALOG, Present_OnInitDialog);
        HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, Present_OnCommand);
        HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, Present_OnClose);
        HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_NOTIFY, Present_OnNotify); //handle WM_NOTIFY
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

*OnInitDialog to create listview control from resource*

```
BOOL Present_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam)
{
//#define     SubclassWindow(hwnd, lpfn)       \
//              ((WNDPROC)SetWindowLong((hwnd), GWL_WNDPROC, (LPARAM)(WNDPROC)(lpfn)))
//#define     SubclassDialog(hwndDlg, lpfn) \
//              ((DLGPROC)SetWindowLong(hwndDlg, DWL_DLGPROC, (LPARAM)(DLGPROC)(lpfn)))

    InitPresLVColumn(hwnd);
    hPresList=GetDlgItem(hwnd,IDC_LIST_PRESLIST); // Create ListView from resource
    SendMessage(hPresList,LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE,0,LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);     
    InitPCBox(hwnd);    
    return FALSE;
}
```

*handle messages from parent after subclassing the listview control*

```
LRESULT CALLBACK PresListView_OnNotify(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HD_NOTIFY *pHDN = (HD_NOTIFY*)lParam;
    if(pHDN->hdr.code == HDN_BEGINTRACKW || pHDN->hdr.code == HDN_BEGINTRACKA \
     || pHDN->hdr.code == HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKA || pHDN->hdr.code == HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKW )
    {
        int i = ListView_GetColumnWidth(hwnd,pHDN->iItem);
        if(0==i)
        { 
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, DWL_MSGRESULT, TRUE);
            return TRUE; 
        } 
    }
    return CallWindowProc((WNDPROC)&Present_OnNotify, hPresList, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

}
```

*handle WM_NOTIFY message by dialog which is the parent of listview control*

```
BOOL Present_OnNotify(HWND hwnd, int id, LPNMHDR lParam)
{
switch(id)
{

    case IDC_LIST_PRESLIST: 
    {
        SubclassWindow(hPresList, (LPARAM)&PresListView_OnNotify);
    }
    break;
}
return TRUE;
```

**EDIT2**

I have edit at:

*E1*      *E2*      *E3*

*OnInitDialog to create listview control from resource*

```
BOOL Present_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam)
{
    InitPresLVColumn(hwnd);
    hPresList=GetDlgItem(hwnd,IDC_LIST_PRESLIST); // Create ListView from resource
    SendMessage(hPresList,LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE,0,LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);   
 E1 SubclassWindow(hPresList, (LPARAM)&PresListView_OnNotify);  
    InitPCBox(hwnd); 
    return FALSE;
}
```

*handle messages from parent after subclassing the listview control*

```
LRESULT CALLBACK PresListView_OnNotify(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HD_NOTIFY *pHDN = (HD_NOTIFY*)lParam;
    if(pHDN->hdr.code == HDN_BEGINTRACKW || pHDN->hdr.code == HDN_BEGINTRACKA \
     || pHDN->hdr.code == HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKA || pHDN->hdr.code == HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKW )
    {
        int i = ListView_GetColumnWidth(hwnd,pHDN->iItem);
        if(0==i)
        { 
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, DWL_MSGRESULT, TRUE);
            return TRUE; 
        } 
    }
 E2 return CallWindowProc(PresListView_OnNotify, hPresList, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

}
```

*handle WM_NOTIFY message by dialog which is the parent of listview control*

```
BOOL Present_OnNotify(HWND hwnd, int id, LPNMHDR lParam)
{
    switch(id)
    {    
        case IDC_LIST_PRESLIST: 
        {
E3          // SubclassWindow(hPresList, (LPARAM)&PresListView_OnNotify);
        }
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? Did you verify that `Present_OnNotify` is being called? Did you verify that `ListView_GetColumnWidth` is returning 0?

Comment: `Present_OnNotify` is being called. But `if(lParam->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKW || lParam->code == HDN_BEGINTRACKA || lParam->code == HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKA || lParam->code == HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKW ){` is false. `lParam->code` seems not get the right value. @RemyLebeau

Comment: What value does `lParam->code` actually contain? Where exactly are you processing `WM_NOTIFY`? The `HDN` notifications are sent from the ListView's internal header control to the ListView itself, not from the ListView to its parent window, so you have to subclass the ListView itself in order to receive them, not catch them in the ListView's parent window.

Comment: Well, I am programming as c style using winapi. How to program as `subclass` in c style? @RemyLebeau

Comment: After you create the ListView using `CreateWindow/Ex()`, use `SetWindowLong/Ptr(GWL_WNDPROC)` or `SetWindowSubClass()` to subclass the ListView. You will then be able to intercept messages that are targetting the ListView directly.

Comment: Sorry for late to reply. I have read some article about subclassing a control (1)[Create-your-own-controls-the-art-of-subclassing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/480/Create-your-own-controls-the-art-of-subclassing) (2)[why-does-this-window-subclassing-code-crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346582/why-does-this-window-subclassing-code-crash). I know that subclassing means to override messages from parent and to handle those messages. But I still confused about how to use it. I have edit my Post on **EDIT**. Can anyone give me some advice. Thanks. @RemyLebeau

Comment: `Present_OnNotify()` is the wrong place to activate the subclass. Do it in `Present_OnInitDialog()` instead, subclassing `hPresList`. Also, when calling `CallWindowProc()` you need to pass the previous WndProc that `SetWindowLong()` returned, not `Present_OnNotify()`. Or use `SetWindowSubClass()`, [which is safer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx). And lastly, `Present_Proc()` should pass unprocessed messages to `DefWindowProc()`.

Comment: I am not familiar with windows message policy. But it works fine for me to `return FALSE` in `Present_Proc()`. I am now edit my code again in **EDIT2**, which still to crash. I did not use `SetWindowSubClass`, since it seems only in XP or 2003 [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I pass `PresListView_OnNotify` not `Present_OnNotify` in `CallWindowProc()` in *E2*. @RemyLebeau

Comment: Unless you need to support Windows 2000 and/or earlier, you really should be using `SetWindowSubClass()`. What you could do is dynamically load it via `GetProcAddress()` and then use it if available, otherwise fallback to `SetWindowLong()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not subclassing the ListView correctly or processing its messages correctly.  Try this instead.

Header file:

```
WNDPROC PrevPresLVWndProc;

BOOL WINAPI Present_Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
BOOL Present_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam);
...    
LRESULT CALLBACK PresListView_OnNotify(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

Source file:

```
BOOL WINAPI Present_Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch( uMsg )
    {
        HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_INITDIALOG, Present_OnInitDialog);
        ...
   }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL Present_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...
    hPresList = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_LIST_PRESLIST); // Create ListView from resource
    ...
    PrevPresLVWndProc = (WNDPROC) GetWindowLongPtr(hPresList, GWL_WNDPROC);
    SetWindowLongPtr(hPresList, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)&PresListView_OnNotify);  
    ...
    return FALSE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK PresListView_OnNotify(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if( uMsg == WM_NOTIFY )
    {
        switch( ((NMHDR*)lParam)->code )
        {
            case HDN_BEGINTRACKA:
            case HDN_BEGINTRACKW:
            case HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKA:
            case HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKW:
            {
                LPNMHEADER pNMHdr = (LPNMHEADER)lParam;

                if( ListView_GetColumnWidth(hwnd, pNMHdr->iItem) == 0 )
                    return TRUE; 

                break;
            }
        }
    }

   return CallWindowProc(PrevPresLVWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

With that said, you really should be using `SetWindowSubClass()` instead:

Header file:

```
BOOL WINAPI Present_Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
BOOL Present_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam);
...    
LRESULT CALLBACK PresListView_OnNotify(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);
```

Source file:

```
BOOL WINAPI Present_Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch( uMsg )
    {
        HANDLE_MSG(hwnd, WM_INITDIALOG, Present_OnInitDialog);
        ...
   }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL Present_OnInitDialog(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndFocus, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ...
    hPresList = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_LIST_PRESLIST); // Create ListView from resource
    ...
    SetWindowSubclass(hPresList, &PresListView_OnNotify, 1, 0);
    ...
    return FALSE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK PresListView_OnNotify(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if( uMsg == WM_NOTIFY )
    {
        switch( ((NMHDR*)lParam)->code )
        {
            case HDN_BEGINTRACKA:
            case HDN_BEGINTRACKW:
            case HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKA:
            case HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKW:
            {
                LPNMHEADER pNMHdr = (LPNMHEADER)lParam;

                if( ListView_GetColumnWidth(hwnd, pNMHdr->iItem) == 0 )
                    return TRUE; 

                break;
            }
        }
    }

   return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

If you really need to support Windows 2000 and/or earlier, you should dynamically load `SetWindowSubClass()` via `GetProcAddress()` so you can use it when available, and fallback to `SetWindowLong()` when not available.

Comment: It work now, thanks. I found that if I return `DefineWindowProc` in `Present_Proc`. `BOOL Present_OnNotify(HWND hwnd, int id, LPNMHDR lParam){   switch(id){   case IDC_LIST_PRESLIST: {     if(lParam->code == NM_RCLICK)   {   MessageBox(hwnd,"Not Define","Right Click",MB_OK);   }` The OK button in MessageBox wont be clickable in `Present_OnNotify`. But if I `return FALSE`, It can be click nomarlly. @RemyLebeau